# C++ / Objective-C++ - How can I store a C++ variable in an NSDictionary?

Tags: c++, objective-c, dictionary, vector

I have a `C++` variable of type `std::vector<std::bitset<128> >` which is defined and populated in a `C++` class (which is called from my `Objective-C++` class.)

I would like to store this object in an `NSDictionary` - or some equivalent of. I clearly can't simply add the `std::vector<std::bitset<128> >` to the NSDictionary because it's not of type `id`.

So my question is this: how can I achieve the same concept? **How can I store a `std::vector<std::bitset<128> >` in a dictionary of sorts?** 
Can I wrap the vector object in an `id` type somehow? Even if it's not a direct dictionary, is there another method I could use? I also need this to be mutable, so I can add key/object's at runtime.

I'v seen `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for. Nor have I found any examples on it being mutable.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Actually `NSValue` seems to be the solution. @Taum's advice is correct for some cases (when you store your objects somewhere and sure your pointers are working). In case you've created some object and it's lifetime is limited, but you need to push this object further, use another `NSValue` method

```
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> cppVector;
NSValue *value=[NSValue valueWithBytes:&cppVector objCType:@encode(std::vector<std::bitset<128>>)];
```

When you need to get this value back:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> cppVector;
[value getValue:&cppVector];
```

That works perfectly for simple structs too.

Comment: I can get first object but next I get: `malloc: *** error for object 0x16f9a8288: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: @user924 look at the place where `next` object was created, it was free'd somewhere further.

Comment: @Astoria they all created in one function

Comment: @user924 probably two cases: 1. It was already released. 2. It wasn't allocated.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a pointer to it in a `NSValue` object. You'll just have to be careful about what owns the `std::vector` and when it should be `free`'d.

Store with:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> *cppVector = myCppObject->methodReturningVector();
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithPointer:cppVector];
[myObjcDictionary setObject:value forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Get C++ object back with:

```
NSValue *value = [myObjcDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"];
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> *cppVector = [value pointerValue]
```

Comment: My C++/ObjC++ is a little rusty but I edited the answer to try and give some code examples. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. I don't have a pointer coming back for my `cppVector` like your example. So I can fix it by using the line `NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithPointer:&cppVector]` but then I can't seem to retrieve it using `[value pointerValue]`. Any ideas?